# JavaScript Dropdown Navigation Menu for Images Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this navigation drop-down menu, that I want to use as a Image ONLY menu. ( It uses javascript and some CSS to animate the effects of movement using the hover effect)

I can't seem to get a hold of it myself.
It works 100% well, when it comes to TEXT by itself, but when i try to put a Image in, it loads in at first, but when the animation starts up, it doesn't show up at all.

Here is the full code for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Kilower/rw9yo6md (For some reason, even the text does not work on jsfiddle, but works fine in the webrowser)

Normal Text Html5

```
<div id='cssmenu' class='align-center'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='News.html'>News</a></li>
    <li><a href='Champions.html'>Champions</a></li>
    <li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>
    <li><a href='Contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Picture Html5

```
    <div class="footer">
  <div id='cssmenu' class='align-center'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='index.html'><img src="style/facebook.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='index.html'><img src="style/twitter.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='index.html'><img src="style/youtube.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='index.html'><img src="style/twitch.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I didn't link in any of the pages etc. and there is a lot of stuff to be changed.
All i want, is for the image to load into the box, after the hover effect.
Any tips/ideas on how to do this ?

CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Galdeano');
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #6699cc
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #6699cc;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #dff2fa;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #0a1827;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle is missing the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue with CSS, however, you have used the cssmenu tag for two ids. I would suggest altering the id tag for first cssmenu and duplicating what CSS you need for the lower menu. If you add the below CSS and give your li tags ids for each graphic you'd like to use, they will be replaced. I've included the [fiddle with the CSS and ids added](http://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/gxjm1hh0/1/). All you should need to alter is background colors of your choosing when they transform.

CSS:

```
#cssmenu > ul > #facebook:hover > a::before,
#facebook li > a:hover::before {
  background-image: url(https://s.w-x.co/facebook.svg?1);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

#cssmenu > ul > #twitter:hover > a::before,
#twitter li > a:hover::before {
  background-image: url(https://s.w-x.co/twitter.svg?1);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

HTML(Only altered two tags for example):

```
<div class="footer">
 <div id='cssmenu' class='align-center'>
<ul>

  <li id="facebook">
    <a href='index.html'><img src="https://s.w-x.co/facebook.svg?1" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="twitter">
    <a href='index.html'><img src="https://s.w-x.co/twitter.svg?1" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='index.html'><img src="style/youtube.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='index.html'><img src="style/twitch.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```